# PHP + JS. onClick change color and run php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am attempting to create like and dislike buttons for a site I am making. Unfortunately progress has not been too good so far. I truly apologize for the way I am writing this but I am new to stack. Back on topic, how would you run php code and change color onClick. So I have a like button right? Its basically a font-awesome icon. When I click on it I want it to be able to turn green. But not only that. I want it to run a PHP code and stay green after click. Also almost forgot to mention I would like it to add a +1 to the 0 as soon as its clicked. So just visual not saving it to server-side just yet.
This is what I got so far:

HTML:

```
 <font color="gray">
 <div id="buttons">
 <i id="like1" onClick="this.style.color='green';" class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i></a>0&nbsp;
 <i id="dislike1" onClick="this.style.color='red';" class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i></a> 0&nbsp;<br>
 Flag?&nbsp;
 <i id="flag1" onClick="this.style.color='red';" class="fa fa-flag"></i></a>&nbsp;
 </font>
 <br>
 <br>
```

And that is all I have for it. I know i'm asking for a lot but I am honestly really confused. I am able to change the color onClick so far but I also needed it to add a +1 visually and to just run php code. For example run echo onClick.

Comment: What you want to do would all be done with JS. PHP is server side. To store the changes you would need to send an ajax request but you said you aren't doing that yet so this is all js interactions. Change your onclick to execute a JS function. Have the JS function change the value and color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally what you would do is fire an ajax request `onclick`, return the total number of likes, and set that as the like text before changing the colour. But since you're only trying to focus on the visual part of this, I'll only comment on that.

Your HTML is malformed. You're missing the end of your div tag and you have end anchor tags but no anchors. I cleaned up your html below. Note that I moved your 0s into the  tags so you can pull it out and increment the value. I also changed the value of the like button `onclick` to a function call.

```
<font color="gray">
    <div id="buttons">
        <i id="like1" onClick="like(this);" class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up">0</i>&nbsp;
        <i id="dislike1" onClick="this.style.color='red';" class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down">0</i>&nbsp;<br/>
        Flag?&nbsp;
        <i id="flag1" onClick="this.style.color='red';" class="fa fa-flag"></i>&nbsp;
    </div>
</font>
<br>
<br>
```

You can then create a function to both change the colour and increment the count

```
function like(obj) {
    // set the colour of the object that was clicked
    obj.style.color = "green";
    // get the innerText for the object that was clicked, parse as int, and increment by 1
    obj.innerText = parseInt(obj.innerText) + 1;
}
```

As a side note, the `<font>` tag is deprecated, you should use CSS to set the colour of text rather than HTML

**Edit**

To toggle:

```
function like(obj) {
    if (obj.style.color === "green") {
        // set obj color to something other than green
        obj.style.color = "gray";
        // get the innerText for the object that was clicked, parse as int, decrement by 1
        obj.innerText = parseInt(obj.innerText) - 1;
    }
    else {
        // we are incrementing, so check the dislike and decrement if necessary
        var dislike = document.getElementById("dislike1");
        if (dislike.style.color === 'red') {
            dislike.style.color = 'gray';
            dislike.innerText = parseInt(dislike.innerText) - 1;
        }
        // set the colour of the object that was clicked
        obj.style.color = "green";
        // get the innerText for the object that was clicked, parse as int, and increment by 1
        obj.innerText = parseInt(obj.innerText) + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey man. You are awesome! Thanks so much for taking your time to help me with this. Your solution is absolutely amazing but one question. How would you make it if you click on it again after you already clicked it, it would unlike it. Kind of like how youtube does it haha. Everything else is good.

Comment: Also forgot. I thought I had server-side but having trouble with ajax. This is what my ajax code looks like, I put it under the function like(obj)          $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "index.php",
  data: { like: "1406" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
});    

    });

Comment: If it's been clicked, it'll be green. So check the colour of the object `onclick` and if it's green reverse the logic above - set to different colour and decrement, else set to green and increment. See example in my edit. What is the problem you are having with the ajax code?

Comment: Okay yes. I get that haha. But the hard part is for example what if someone clicks like. then someone clicks dislike. It shouldn't be liked anymore. Because in this example if you like a video and then you click the dislike button they both light-up and both get +1 until you click on one. As soon as we can get this resolved I'll make sure to mark this as the correct answer. Once again thanks so much :)

Comment: So then in your respective functions (`like()`, `dislike()`) you'd need to check the other object's colour and decrement it if necessary. See edits for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <font color="gray">
 <div id="buttons">
 <i id="like1" onClick="myFunction();" class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up">    </i></a>0&nbsp;
 <i id="dislike1" onClick="myFunctiondislike();" class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down">    </i></a> 0&nbsp;<br>
 Flag?&nbsp;
 <i id="flag1" onClick="this.style.color='red';" class="fa fa-flag"></i>    </a>&nbsp;
 </font>
 <br>
 <br>

 <script>
 function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("like1").style.color = "#ff3";
 }
 function myFunctiondislike() {
 document.getElementById("dislike1").style.color = "#000";
 } 
function myFunctionflag() {
 document.getElementById("flag1").style.color = "#FFF";
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (jQuery library needed):

HTML:

```
<span class="btn like">Like</span>
<span class="btn dislike">Dislike</span>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $(".dislike").css("display", "none");
    $(".btn").on("click", function(){
        var _text = $(this).text();
        if(_text === "Like")
        {
            $(".btn").css({"display":"inline-block"});
            $(this).css({"display":"none"});            
        }
        else
        {
            $(".btn").css({"display":"inline-block"});
            $(this).css({"display":"none"});
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
span{ background-color:#999; padding:10px; color:#FFF; cursor:pointer;}
```

jsfiddle link:

[link] http://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/bxgg4ry5/